# vue.js see if input matches regex

Tags: regex, vue.js, compare

I have a input field that I like to compare to several regex.
If the input is correct, the method should be executed.

I think I'm doing it completely wrong.

```
<p class="control">
    <input ref="barcode" id="BarcodeInput" v-model="barcode" v-on:keyup.enter="processBarcode" class="input" type="text"  placeholder="Barcode" autofocus />
    </p>
    <p class="control">
    <button v-on:click="processBarcode" class="button is-primary" >Go!</button>
</p>
```

method:

```
      if (document.getElementById("BarcodeInput").value == "31334866-001"){
```

Now i can put the barcode in the textbox and i can use the methode.

If i try:

```
      if (document.getElementById("BarcodeInput").value == "^\d{8}-\d{3}$"){
```

the Barcode: 31334866-001 doesnt work.

Comment: You could use [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) like `if(/^\d{8}-\d{3}$/.test(document.getElementById("BarcodeInput").value)) {}`

Answer (score 0):

So you'll want to first use a `v-model` for the barcode input linked to your `data`. This will save you the trouble of getting the element. Then do your validation in the `processBarcode` function.

If you want to clear the box, just clear the `v-model` variable stored in data (with two-way binding, changing one changes the other).